# Unable to upgrade hive to 2.3.2 in cloudera VM

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I upgraded `hive` version in `cloudera vm` to `2.3.2'. It is installed successfully and I copied`hive-site.xml`file from older`/hive/conf`folder to the newer`conf`folder and there is no problem with the metastore. However when I am executing query like`'drop table table_name'` then it throws below exception :

```
FAILED: SemanticException Unable to fetch table table_name. Invalid method name: 'get_table_req'
```

Below is my `hive-site.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

  <!-- Hive Configuration can either be stored in this file or in the hadoop configuration files  -->
  <!-- that are implied by Hadoop setup variables.                                                -->
  <!-- Aside from Hadoop setup variables - this file is provided as a convenience so that Hive    -->
  <!-- users do not have to edit hadoop configuration files (that may be managed as a centralized -->
  <!-- resource).                                                                                 -->

  <!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>cloudera</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.8.1-cdh4.0.0.jar</value>
    <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://127.0.0.1:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Below are my `bashrc` variables:

```
#Setting hive variables
export HIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin"
export PATH="$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

**NOTE:** I am able to create tables but when I execute any select query it fails and throws the above exception. Where am I going wrong? Do I need to copy any other file as well ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check your metastore version and upprade metastore version